# Effective method for waterproofing a tube through a hole drilled in the side of a bucket?

Tags: plumbing, waterproofing, sealing, plastic

How to prevent water leaking around a tube passed through the side of a bucket? The bucket is plastic approx 1mm thick wall and the tube is rubber with 6mm outside diameter.

I drilled a 6mm hole and passed the tube through it, applying Araldite glue/resin around the on the inside and silicon sealant on the outside. I happened to have these lying around and decided were worth trying, but it doesn't feel robust at all.

What is the proper way of doing this? Preferably cheap and easily mass produced as long as the solution is robust and reliable.

Comment: "Doesn't feel robust"  have you even tested the connection? Wiggled? etc.?   And why would you consider mass production without consulting a product engineer, who most likely would tell you to contract out  a custom snap-fit gasket?

Comment: A 1/4" nipple with washers and a rubber gasket on the inside would be strong and not cost much. And nuts to pull it tight.

Comment: @Carl: It's a DIY project and I am very much an amateur, when I say mass produced I just mean an easily reproducible low cost solution that is reliable. If I am using the wrong terminology please accept my apologies. I've tested it as you have described and it doesn't leak any water. I am just sure there is a 'proper way' of doing it rather than squeezing some glue around the join. I'm trying to learn :)

Comment: @EdBeal: Thanks for putting me on the right track Ed. I found these, what do you think? ebay.co.uk/itm/10Pcs-Waterproof-Fixing-Gland-Connector-PG7-for-3-5-6mm-Dia-Cable-Wire-/201469149587

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want is called a bulkhead fitting.

[image] [image]

This has a gasket to make a seal against the container, and threads to connect to whatever fittings you need. Some have outside threads on only one side, or you can get them with inside and outside threads on both sides, and they cone in all sorts of different sizes and materials.

You can screw in a 6mm push-fit connector, for example:

[image]

Comment: That is what I was thinking of but could not think of the name. I have used them on water tanks that were pressurized and pool filter housings, good luck on your project.

Comment: Thank you. After researching different types of bulkhead connector I ended up going with one of these: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/6mm-to-6mm-Bulkhead-Push-in-Fitting-B129A/110835049287